How to delete folders in program files folder using cmd
I'm using cmd to run a software installation cycle. The steps are install - uninstall - delete associated folders - install new version.
The installation adds folders in C:\Program Files so I need to delete these folders. However, cmd returns "The system cannot find the file specified."
The code is rmdir C:\Program Files\folder /s /q. If it's not in C:\Program Files, the folder can be deleted. So I assume something is protecting these folders even though I'm running the cmd as administrator. How to delete folders in program files folder using cmd?

That is a NO GO. Any program in %ProgramFiles% or %ProgramFiles(x86)% is usually installed with an installer executable which does not only create a folder in one of these two folders with the program files of the application or application suite but usually also with creating one or more shortcuts in one of the folders of Windows Start menu and/or one of the Windows Desktop folders, adding keys and values to registry and creating perhaps also other folders and files like in %APPDATA% or %LOCALAPPDATA%. A program should be always uninstalled using its uninstaller.

The simple deletion of the folder with the files of a program can result in lots of remaining keys and values in Windows registry and files and folders in file system. It is even possible that the uninstall as registered in Windows registry is not possible anymore after the deletion of the program files folder and the user cannot even install the application again in same or a newer version because of the necessary uninstall of current version using the uninstaller before doing the install fails due to deletion of the program files folder of the application.

What you try to do is a corruption of the installed application. Don't do that! PS: Open a command prompt window, run cmd /? and read the output usage help. There is explained on last output help page that a file name (or any other argument string) containing a space or one of these characters &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ (or literally to interpret <>| like in a password) must be enclosed in ". Type in the command prompt window C:\Prog and press multiple times the key TAB and see how the file/folder name completion of cmd.exe suggests matching file/folder names without or with ".

The deletion of a program files folder is only okay if the uninstaller was already executed first successfully and a Windows restart was done to complete the uninstall process by running the registered pending rename operations by Windows to delete files and folders which could not be deleted during the uninstallation process because of being used by a running application and the program files folder still exists with subdirectories or files because of the uninstaller is not good coded and does not remove all files and folders of the installed application.

@Mofi Sorry if I wasn't specific, but yes, I am trying to delete remainder folders in Program Files when "the uninstaller was already executed first successfully and a Windows restart was done". The uninstaller uninstalls the product but does not remove folders. To ensure the later version installed does not get messed up, anything related in Program Files needs to be removed.

@Mofi if what you meant is "there is absolutely no way to delete any folder in Program Files using cmd even though the uninstaller was already executed first successfully and a Windows restart was done" and "one must manually remove these folders", then I will take it...

It is absolutely fine when the uninstaller was already executed and the remaining program files and folders are deleted with a batch script. The batch script can also check with execution of %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager" /v PendingFileRenameOperations 1>nul 2>nul and evaluation of the exit code if this registry value exists or not. If it does not exist after the uninstall, there is no restart of Windows necessary and it is safe to remove the folder and immediately install the application in a newer version.

Spaces in command line commands are used to separate arguments. When you have a space in an argument (like the space in the folder name "Program Files"), you need to use quotes or escaping like the following:
rmdir "C:\Program Files\folder" /s /q

One exception: chdir/cd can take a directory name/path containing space(s) without quoting (although quoting also works)

@dave_thompson_085 Yes, that is right as explained by the usage help output on running cd /? or chdir /? or help cd or help chdir. It is nevertheless highly recommended using cd/chdir with directory path always enclosed in ". The directory path could contain also & which would be interpreted by cmd.exe as unconditional command operator or && interpreted as conditional command operator on not enclosing the complete directory path in ". Run md "C:\Temp\Development & Test 100% (!)"  and try next cd C:\Temp\Development & Test 100% (!) which fails.
